# Can a VIPER architecture have multiple UIViewControllers inside a single module?

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, clean-architecture, viper-architecture

Can a VIPER architecture have multiple UIViewControllers inside a single module?

Examples of VIPER architecture usually have only one UIViewController in one VIPER module.

I'm wondering if multiple UIViewControllers share closely related logics and UIControllers themselves are also closely related, a single VIPER module may have multiple UIViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VIPER is a pattern, not a set of strict rules. Therefore, you may have multiple UIViewControllers inside a single module, when it makes it easier for you.